# What is b / ||w|| in support vector machine?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

In the picture of [SVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm8ZY.png) from Wikipedia, at the lower left corner - pointed by the red arrow, there's b / ||w||. How is that calculated? In other words, why is the line in the picture b / ||w||? Thanks.

Comment: it only indicates the distance to the origin `(0,0)` not sure why this is relevant for the graph

Comment: Thanks for the prompt advice. But it shows the distance to (0,0) is b / ||w||, right? How is that calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line represents the affine subspace of points x, whose scalar product with the weight vector w yields b. As w is typically not a unit vector (i.e. need not have length 1), one has to divide b by the norm (the "length") of w  to get the actual distance from the origin. 
More precisely: imagine a vector x starting at the origin and reaching out to a point on the red line and let u be the unit vector in the direction of w, i.e. u = w / ||w||. Then the scalar product of x and u multiplied with u is the projection of x onto the unit vector u and its length corresponds to the distance of the red line from the origin. If you calculate the scalar product of `<x,w>` (written as x*w in the graphics) instead, you still get a projection on u, which has length b (that's actually how b is defined), so to get back the distance from the origin one has to calculate b/||w||.

Comment: Thanks. But may I ask a further question? If x is projected on u, the projection should be (x w/||w||) w/||w||, right? Then how does it come down to b/||w||?

Comment: The scalar product (x w/||w||) that scales the projected vector to a particular length is the distance of the red line from the origin. To get the distance from the origin you need to project some vector x pointing from the origin (0,0) to a point on the red line onto a unit-length vector orthogonal to this line. w is such an orthogonal vector, but it does not necessarily have unit length, so the scalar product with w gives a value that is "misscaled" by ||w||. We know, that (x w) = b for points x on the red line. So the distance from the origin is then (x w/||w||) = b/||w||.